# How to develope two rails app in single root directory?

Tags: mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.1

The problem description is as :

1. I have an existing app. developed in php. I have to transform that in rails.
2. I have to develop enterprise version of same point 1 app. with additional functionality and complexity for enterprise related work . I have developed this one as enterprise_app as app. name.
3. I have implemented devise n pundit in point 2 app.(enterprise) but I need to implement authentication and authorization on my own for point 1 app. in rails.
4. I would not like to mix the model's from both apps. or should I do that (your suggestions), since basic functionalities are same. But I would not like to break point2 enterprise app. in any cost.
5. I would like to have different interfaces for both app.
6. I would like to have point 1 app. running from inside of point 2's app.

   7. I would like to use same db for both app. but with different tables, and the major point to keep in mind is - there should be no security related problems for point2_enterprise app. from tables and code from point1 app. Is my sense for security wright or there can or can't be security issues (need your knowledge).

   Now, I would like to know - what will be the best approach for above scenarios?
   Are my assumptions above proper, I would like to know your suggestions and assumptions.

I have been working in rails for almost 6 months, I think this is a great challenge for me. and time to learn and implement rails-internals and OOP.

What necessary concepts should I need to know and learn for solving above problem?

Hoping you guys got the clue, else please comment, I will try to clear as possible. Happy Coding guys !!!